# How can I get the number of pages in a PDF file in Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf, pdflib

Is there any Perl script to read multiple PDF files and get the number of pages in it?

By using PDFlib or pdftet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about just using Perl with the  PDF::API2?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use PDF::API2;

foreach $doc (@ARGV)
{
    $pdf = PDF::API2->open($doc);
    $pages = $pdf->pages;
    $totalpages += $pages;

    print "$doc contains $pages pages\n";
}

print "Total pages of pdf pages = $totalpages\n";
```